# Qual o melhor jeito de se obter o RadioButton que foi escolhido pelo usuário?

Tags: c#, winforms

Meu programa tem 5 `RadioButton` em um dos `Panel` que eu não renomeei e assim ficou `Panel1`, então só um pode ser escolhido.

Eu criei uma lista com todos os `RadioButtons`, depois de clicado em um botão eu tentei usar o código abaixo para iterar a propriedade `Tag` item do marcado:

```
// this.ListaRadios é minha lista de RadioButtons

var variacao = from item in this.ListaRadios //Esta parte dá erro:

// Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
// 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton>'.
// 'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive
// for 'System.Linq'?

               where item.Checked = true
               select (string)item.Tag;
```

Além do erro que está dando, tem jeito mais eficiente de se fazer isso?

Como seria um Linq pra iterar somente os `RadioButtons` de um `Panel` e em seguida o único marcado?

Comment: Em relação ao erro verifique se tem a referência ao *System.Core assembly* e se indicou o *Namespace* com `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var resultado = "";

    foreach (Control control in this.Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is RadioButton)
        {
            RadioButton radio = control as RadioButton;

            if (radio.Checked)
            {
                resultado = radio.Text; //Text ou qualquer outra propriedade
            }
        }
    }
```